# Detecting gps when ionic app is accessed through ionic view?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to detect whether gps is enabled using cordova diagnostics plugin in my ionic app. I had uploaded the application to ionic view to test it on my android device.

Test code look something like this :

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() { 

 if (window.cordova) {  

  cordova.plugins.diagnostic.isLocationEnabled(function(enabled) {
    $ionicPopup.alert({
        title: 'Testing location',
        template: 'gps enabled : ' + enabled
     }).then(function(res) {
        console.log('error');
     });
   }, function(error) {
     console.log('error in plugin');
   });

}

});
```

This code is added in run method of ionic app.
I am not able to understand why it does not work.
Is this has something to do with application being accessed through ionic view?

Comment: If you're using Ionic try and use a plugin by ng-cordova first if you can first

Comment: It is possible.try to run or emulate on device and see what happens.

Comment: @Raja `cordova-plugins-diagnostic` is not supported by ion view right now, check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunatelly not all cordova plugins are supported when using ion view.

On the official documentation there is a list with the supported plugins and as you can find out cordova diagnostic is not one of them.
My guess is that in the future there will be support for the diagnostic plugin since it seems to be very popular.

[List of supported plugins](https://docs.ionic.io/tools/view/#supported-plugins)